# Default Roles Cannot Login Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am configuring a postgres database and I see that the default roles, pg_monitor, pg_read_all_settings, pg_read_all_stats, pg_signal_backend, and pg_stat_scan_tables all cannot login. I'm not sure what the first step would be. Here is the output of \l and \du:

```
postgres=# \l
                                   List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |    Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------
 confdb02  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
           |          |          |             |             | confluence=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres            +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=# \du
                                                            List of roles
      Role name       |                   Attributes                   |                          Member of
----------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 confluence           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
 pg_monitor           | Cannot login                                   | {pg_read_all_settings,pg_read_all_stats,pg_stat_scan_tables}
 pg_read_all_settings | Cannot login                                   | {}
 pg_read_all_stats    | Cannot login                                   | {}
 pg_signal_backend    | Cannot login                                   | {}
 pg_stat_scan_tables  | Cannot login                                   | {}
 postgres             | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

Thanks!
```

Comment: These are not meant to be `LOGIN` rioes. They are system roles that can be granted to other, possibly login, roles. See here [Default Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/default-roles.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, so are these system roles OK? Is this what I should expect to see in a normal installation?

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look at this section [Roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/user-manag.html) in the docs. It will give you an idea of how roles are used.

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute LOGIN to the role, with this command:

```
ALTER ROLE username LOGIN;
```

Don't forget the user needs a password:

```
ALTER ROLE username WITH PASSWORD 'user_secret_password';
```

You will also need to give permission over the Database, like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE databasename TO username;
```

The list of permissions are these:

```
SELECT
INSERT
UPDATE
DELETE
TRUNCATE
REFERENCES
TRIGGER
CREATE
TEMPORARY or TEMP
EXECUTE
USAGE
ALL PRIVILEGES
```